# Do Event Logs record file copies and moves on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-event-log

For an information security audit, we need to show if users copied or moved files from a particular location on our file server. As far as I know, if a user can read a file they can copy it and this action is not recorded in the security logs, same with moving a file.

Is there any record in the Event or security logs on Windows Server 2012 that records this, or do I need a 3rd party package to deal with this?

Comment: Not by default but you can enable auditing that will then log those actions to the event log.

Comment: Thank you. Can you make this an answer? I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not by default but you can enable auditing that will then log those actions to the event log.

Comment: Okay, follow up; will it show a copy from a server to a workstation or only copies done on volumes on a server?